# Problems with checkboxes in form

Tags: php, forms

I am having issues getting my checkboxes to post using php. I've tried several ways from all the tutorials, but nothing works.

HTML

```
  <label for="Ifyescheckone">Sealed?</label>
  <ul>
   <li><input class="icheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Ifyescheckone[]"     id="Ifyescheckone1" value="Protect">
   <label for="Ifyescheckone1" class="ilabel">Protect</label></li>

  <li><input class="icheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Ifyescheckone[]"   id="Ifyescheckone2" value="Return of">
  <label for="Ifyescheckone2" class="ilabel">Return of</label></li>

 <li><input class="icheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Ifyescheckone[]" id="Ifyescheckone3"  value="Protect against">
  <label for="Ifyescheckone3" class="ilabel">Protect against</label></li>

  <li><input class="icheckbox" type="checkbox" name="Ifyescheckone[]"    id="Ifyescheckone4" value="May indicate"><label for="Ifyescheckone4" class="ilabel">May    indicate</label></li>
```

PHP

```
  <?php echo $_POST["Ifyescheckone"]; ?>
  <?php echo $_POST["Ifyescheckone" $value]; ?>
```

Comment: The first example should work. The second is nonsense. What output do you get? What do you expect? How are you submitting the form data? Are you checking any of the checkboxes? What does the HTTP request look like in your browser's developer tools' Net tab?

Comment: Can you add the result of `print_r($_POST["Ifyescheckone"]);`

Comment: Make sure you are using method="POST" in form tag and also try to var_dump($_POST)

Comment: `<label for="Ifyescheckone">Sealed?</label>` should be a `<fieldset>` with a `<legend>`. `<label>` is for single controls, not groups of them.

Comment: Are you definitely using POST to submit, and not GET?

Comment: Remove the second line from the PHP. It's almost certainly tripping up on that line (a parse error, before it actually processes the instructions). Also, look into enabling error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

try this, Selected values in one line,

```
  echo $checkbox = implode(", ", $_POST["Ifyescheckone"]);
```

OR

```
 <?php foreach($_POST["Ifyescheckone"] as $value){
      echo $value; 
      echo " <br/> ";
   }
  ?>
```